# Dynamic menu and links

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a navigation:

```
Cars->Car 1->Menu
```

Where `Car 1` is a dynamic value. I choose a `Car X`, and I get a menu for `Car X`. How to do this?

I mean that when choosing `Car X`, in links was added value `Car=x`.

```
cars->car_id->maintenances->index
cars->car_id->maintenances->maintenance_id->edit
cars->car_id->repairs->index
cars->car_id->repairs->repair_id->edit
```

Please help. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Show us your routes and controller file.

Comment: Now I just use as static menu. In routers `Route::resource('repairs', 'RepairsController');`. I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your tables fields but I guess you could do something like this:

```
<ul>
@foreach($cars as $car)
  <li>
    <a href="{!! action('MeintenancesController@index', $car->id)!!}">{!! $car->name!!}</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    @foreach($car->meintenances as $meintenance)
      <li>
        <a href="{!! action('MeintenancesController@edit, $meintenance->id) !!}">{!!$meintenance->name!!}</a>
      </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
  </li>
@enforeach
</ul>
```

Same for repairs

Comment: The problem is not this. Problems in use `car_id`. All links must have `car_id`.

Comment: Tren you pass car_id as argument

Comment: In every link I will have to set `car_id` as argument. It is problem.

Comment: Please post here the edit and index methods from repairsController

Comment: Now I just use as static menu. Index methods from repairsController to show list for all cars.

Comment: If you don't post your code here we can not help you

Comment: Now I just show all list `repairs` without `car_id`.Index metod: `$repairs = DB::table("repairs")->paginate(); return view('repairs.index', compact('repairs'));`

Comment: $repairs = DB::table("repairs")->join('cars', 'repairs.car_id', '=', 'cars.id')->paginate()